# @Profile in @Configuration --> Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have 2 configurations in one Spring Batch application, each of them is annotated with @Profile

```
@Configuration
@Profile("jobA")
public class JobA {
...
...

   @Bean
   public Job job(Step stepForA) {
        ...
   }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@Profile("jobB")
public class JobB {
...
...

   @Bean
   public Job job(Step stepForB) {
        ...
   }

}
```

I have a test to run JobB

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestJobB.Context.class, JobB.class, JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@ActiveProfiles("testB")
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
public class TestJobB extends AbstractTestJob {
...
}
```

Running the test gives me the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

The weird thing is, if I dont use @Profile in the 2 Configurations, everything is fine.  Any annotation I am missing here?

Thanks, Hadi

Comment: Remove the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation. You are trying very hard to outsmart the framework.

Comment: Where is the bean `jobLauncherTestUtils` defined? This bean autowires a `Job` bean from the test context, so make sure it is part of the profile you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your profile names. According to your example, the two configurations are annotated with `@Profile("jobA")` and `@Profile("jobB")` respectively. However in your test, you have defined the profile as `@ActiveProfiles("testB")`.

As you noticed, removal of the `@Profile` annotation in the two configurations they will always be enabled if they are imported correctly. Consequently, the test will use `JobB` since it declared in the  `@SpringBootTest` annotation.